# In Win32, how can the colour of STATIC text be changed?

Tags: winapi

I have some static text on a window which is black, and I would like to change it at runtime using a Colour Chooser dialog. I have successfully obtained the colour, now I just need to change the text! I have read that the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message is the one to handle, although this appears to only be for when the control is initially drawn to the screen. Could `WM_PAINT` be used?

The code for setting the colour I have so far is (in `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` case):

```
if ((HWND)lParam == GetDlgItem(hWnd, uLabelId)
{
    SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, crLabelTextColour);
    return (BOOL)CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU));
}
```

I may have got entirely the wrong end of the stick approaching this issue, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track with `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.  If you want to change the color, then invalidate the control (probably by using [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  That will cause it to be repainted.  When it's repainted, your `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handler will be invoked again.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Are you aware that it's the parent dialog that receives `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`, not the control itself?
- The `return (BOOL)...` looks weird - in which function does this code live?  You should be returning an LRESULT from your window proc.
- You're leaking a brush every time - you should maintain a single brush and return that brush each time.  Windows doesn't clean up the brush.

Comment: Thanks! I was aware that `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is a notifcation. The return statement is just something I got from another example - I don't really like it either! Thanks for alerting me to the brush - I shall look into that!